# Why Oracle Linux doesn't recognize virtio?

Tags: centos, oracle-linux, virtio

On KVM-libvirt I have setup a Oracle Linux VM (Oracle Linux 7)

I run it with SATA, but I want to use virtio

I put the virtio disk and network..but on boot don't load the driver, or better, the driver is loaded (`lspci` reports `virtio_pci` for the network card!)

If I do `modprobe virtio_net` the device disappears from `lspci`!

I have tried with `dracut`, then reboot, but nothing changes

```
dracut --add-drivers "virtio_pci virtio_blk virtio_scsi virtio_net virtio_ring virtio" -f -v /boot/initramfs-`uname -r`.img `uname -r`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With latest kernel 4.1.*(included in oracle linux for security fix for metldown bug) works perfect.